Expo iOS Build failed: Error running an expo development build
So I recently updated my expo to SDK 51 and created a new development build, but when I tried to run npx eas build --profile development-simulator --platform ios.
For more details, I'm using NativeWind ^4.1.23.
Eas.json:
"cli": {
    "version": ">= 9.2.0"
},
"build": {
    "development": {
        "developmentClient": true,
        "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "development-simulator": {
        "developmentClient": true,
        "distribution": "internal",
        "ios": {
            "simulator": true
        }
    },
    "preview": {
        "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
},
"submit": {
    "production": {}
}

I've ran to this error :

yarn run v1.22.21
$ /Users/expo/workingdir/build/frontend/node_modules/.bin/expo export:embed --eager --platform ios --dev false
Starting Metro Bundler


tailwindcss(ios) rebuilding...
done
|
| <--- Last few GCs --->
|
| [2058:0x130008000]    51620 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2030.9 (2084.3) -> 2030.9 (2084.3) MB, 1920.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.147, current mu = 0.102) allocation failure; GC in old space requested
|
iOS Bundling failed 89196ms node_modules/expo-router/entry.js (3958 modules)


global.css: A jest worker process (pid=2058) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGTERM, exitCode=null. Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred.
SyntaxError: global.css: A jest worker process (pid=2058) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGTERM, exitCode=null. Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred.
Error: A jest worker process (pid=2058) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGTERM, exitCode=null. Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred.
at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/frontend/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:370:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I've tried changing path to global.css but non of these examples on internet helped.
Currently the path to global.css is import "../global.css"; but still same error.
